# Dataframes Tests Fail During While Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mql5, metatrader5

I'm trying to write a program that will stream candlestick data from MT5.  The logic of the program should be:

1. Download 72 1-minute candles worth of data for BTCUSD.
2. Check the terminal every 10 seconds to see if a new 1 minute candle has finished forming.
3. If a new candle has formed, add it to the end of the 72 candle dataframe and delete the oldest index (I haven't coded the deletion part).

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
import pandas as pd
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal
import time
 
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500) 
pd.set_option('display.width', 1500)      
 
if not mt5.initialize(): # start mt5
    print("initialize failed")
    mt5.shutdown()
 
account="HIDDEN" # account info to log into broker
authorized=mt5.login(account, server="HIDDEN")
if authorized:
    print("Authorized")
else:
    print("failed to connect at account #{}, error code: {}".format(account, mt5.last_error()))
 
# download last 72 bars of BTCUSD
cndl_72 = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos("BTCUSD", mt5.TIMEFRAME_M1, 1, 72)
cndl_72_df = pd.DataFrame(cndl_72) # convert to DataFrame
cndl_72_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(cndl_72_df['time'], unit='s') # some time conversion thing from the documentation I don't really get it
 
while True: # start the stream
    cndl_last = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos("BTCUSD", mt5.TIMEFRAME_M1, 1, 1) # download latest bar
    cndl_last_df = pd.DataFrame(cndl_last) # convert to DataFrame
    cndl_last_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(cndl_last_df['time'], unit='s') # do necessary time conversion
 
    cndl_72_last_df = pd.DataFrame(cndl_72_df.iloc[-1]) # find the last index of the 72 candle dataframe
    cndl_72_last_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(cndl_72_df['time'], unit='s') # perform necessary time conversion
 
# check if the most recent bar is the same as the most recent entry in cndl_72_df
    try:
        assert_frame_equal([cndl_last_df, cndl_72_last_df])
        print("True", cndl_last_df, cndl_72_last_df) # printing both just for testing purposes.  produces bad output seen below.
    except:
        print("False", cndl_last_df, cndl_72_last_df)
        pd.concat([cndl_72_df, cndl_last_df]) # append latest candle to the end of the 72 candle dataframe
        print(cndl_72_df) # prints the edited 72 candle data frame, which doesn't show any changes as it should
    time.sleep(10)
```

The output is:

```
Authorized
False                  time      open     high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0 2022-02-21 02:10:00  38341.52  38362.1  38333.09  38347.18           65     900            0                               71 time
time         2022-02-21 02:10:00  NaT
open                    38341.52  NaT
high                     38362.1  NaT
low                     38333.09  NaT
close                   38347.18  NaT
tick_volume                   65  NaT
spread                       900  NaT
real_volume                    0  NaT
                  time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0  2022-02-21 00:59:00  38868.19  38936.00  38809.08  38936.00           57     900            0
1  2022-02-21 01:00:00  38933.90  38988.80  38889.51  38928.32          170     900            0
2  2022-02-21 01:01:00  38927.82  38936.33  38826.26  38874.85          153    1460            0
3  2022-02-21 01:02:00  38875.26  38891.40  38789.51  38798.90          160    2431            0
4  2022-02-21 01:03:00  38804.90  38811.40  38688.26  38707.40          125    1371            0
..                 ...       ...       ...       ...       ...          ...     ...          ...
67 2022-02-21 02:06:00  38263.27  38276.48  38217.98  38229.26           63     900            0
68 2022-02-21 02:07:00  38220.48  38341.98  38211.98  38305.03           79     900            0
69 2022-02-21 02:08:00  38308.01  38309.77  38263.59  38295.85           81     900            0
70 2022-02-21 02:09:00  38292.76  38339.90  38281.08  38338.51           71     900            0
71 2022-02-21 02:10:00  38341.52  38362.10  38333.09  38347.18           65     900            0

[72 rows x 8 columns]
False                  time      open     high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0 2022-02-21 02:10:00  38341.52  38362.1  38333.09  38347.18           65     900            0                               71 time
time         2022-02-21 02:10:00  NaT
open                    38341.52  NaT
high                     38362.1  NaT
low                     38333.09  NaT
close                   38347.18  NaT
tick_volume                   65  NaT
spread                       900  NaT
real_volume                    0  NaT
                  time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0  2022-02-21 00:59:00  38868.19  38936.00  38809.08  38936.00           57     900            0
1  2022-02-21 01:00:00  38933.90  38988.80  38889.51  38928.32          170     900            0
2  2022-02-21 01:01:00  38927.82  38936.33  38826.26  38874.85          153    1460            0
3  2022-02-21 01:02:00  38875.26  38891.40  38789.51  38798.90          160    2431            0
4  2022-02-21 01:03:00  38804.90  38811.40  38688.26  38707.40          125    1371            0
..                 ...       ...       ...       ...       ...          ...     ...          ...
67 2022-02-21 02:06:00  38263.27  38276.48  38217.98  38229.26           63     900            0
68 2022-02-21 02:07:00  38220.48  38341.98  38211.98  38305.03           79     900            0
69 2022-02-21 02:08:00  38308.01  38309.77  38263.59  38295.85           81     900            0
70 2022-02-21 02:09:00  38292.76  38339.90  38281.08  38338.51           71     900            0
71 2022-02-21 02:10:00  38341.52  38362.10  38333.09  38347.18           65     900            0

[72 rows x 8 columns]
False                  time      open     high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0 2022-02-21 02:10:00  38341.52  38362.1  38333.09  38347.18           65     900            0                               71 time
time         2022-02-21 02:10:00  NaT
open                    38341.52  NaT
high                     38362.1  NaT
low                     38333.09  NaT
close                   38347.18  NaT
tick_volume                   65  NaT
spread                       900  NaT
real_volume                    0  NaT
                  time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0  2022-02-21 00:59:00  38868.19  38936.00  38809.08  38936.00           57     900            0
1  2022-02-21 01:00:00  38933.90  38988.80  38889.51  38928.32          170     900            0
2  2022-02-21 01:01:00  38927.82  38936.33  38826.26  38874.85          153    1460            0
3  2022-02-21 01:02:00  38875.26  38891.40  38789.51  38798.90          160    2431            0
4  2022-02-21 01:03:00  38804.90  38811.40  38688.26  38707.40          125    1371            0
..                 ...       ...       ...       ...       ...          ...     ...          ...
67 2022-02-21 02:06:00  38263.27  38276.48  38217.98  38229.26           63     900            0
68 2022-02-21 02:07:00  38220.48  38341.98  38211.98  38305.03           79     900            0
69 2022-02-21 02:08:00  38308.01  38309.77  38263.59  38295.85           81     900            0
70 2022-02-21 02:09:00  38292.76  38339.90  38281.08  38338.51           71     900            0
71 2022-02-21 02:10:00  38341.52  38362.10  38333.09  38347.18           65     900            0
```

As you can see the try/except repeatedly tests false which shouldn't happen.  If the most recent candle is downloaded, the output should be True, and when the program detects a new candle the output should be False.

This question is a continuation of this question I asked earlier: [Compare Last Index of a Dataframe with a Single Index Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71199066/compare-last-index-of-a-dataframe-with-a-single-index-dataframe)

In an attempt to solve my own problem I made numerous changes to the code.  The question became harder and harder for the public to answer as I kept making changes and new issues started arising.  This question was created in an attempt to make things less confusing.

EDIT #1, new code with changes as suggested:

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
import pandas as pd
import time

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500) 
pd.set_option('display.width', 1500)      

if not mt5.initialize(): # start mt5
    print("initialize failed")
    mt5.shutdown()

account="HIDDEN" # account info to log into broker
authorized=mt5.login(account, server="HIDDEN")
if authorized:
    print("Authorized")
else:
    print("failed to connect at account #{}, error code: {}".format(account, mt5.last_error()))

# download last 10 bars of BTCUSD
cndl_72 = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos("BTCUSD", mt5.TIMEFRAME_M1, 1, 72)
cndl_72_df = pd.DataFrame(cndl_72) # convert to DataFrame
cndl_72_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(cndl_72_df['time'], unit='s') # some time conversion thing from the documentation I don't really get it

while True: # start the stream
    cndl_last = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos("BTCUSD", mt5.TIMEFRAME_M1, 1, 1) # download latest bar
    cndl_last_df = pd.DataFrame(cndl_last) # convert to DataFrame
    cndl_last_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(cndl_last_df['time'], unit='s') # do necessary time conversion

    cndl_72_last_df = (cndl_72_df.iloc[-1]).to_frame()
    #below line throws an error.
    cndl_72_last_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(cndl_72_last_df['time'], unit='s')

# check if the most recent bar is the same as the most recent entry in bars_frame
    if cndl_last_df.equals(cndl_72_last_df):
        print("True", cndl_last_df, cndl_72_last_df)
    else:
        print("False", cndl_last_df, cndl_72_last_df)
        cndl_72_df = pd.concat([cndl_72_df, cndl_last_df])
        print(cndl_72_df)
    time.sleep(10)
```

new code throws this error:

```
Authorized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hello\Documents\projects\alerter_venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3621, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 144, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 41, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: 'time'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hello\Documents\projects\alerter_venv\main_2.py", line 31, in <module>
    cndl_72_last_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(cndl_72_last_df['time'], unit='s')
  File "C:\Users\hello\Documents\projects\alerter_venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3505, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\hello\Documents\projects\alerter_venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'time'
```

EDIT #2:
new code with suggestions:

```
import MetaTrader6 as mt5
import pandas as pd
import time

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500) 
pd.set_option('display.width', 1500)      

if not mt5.initialize(): # start mt5
    print("initialize failed")
    mt5.shutdown()

account="HIDDEN" # account info to log into broker
authorized=mt5.login(account, server="HIDDEN")
if authorized:
    print("Authorized")
else:
    print("failed to connect at account #{}, error code: {}".format(account, mt5.last_error()))

# download last 10 bars of BTCUSD
cndl_72 = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos("BTCUSD", mt5.TIMEFRAME_M1, 1, 72)
cndl_72_df = pd.DataFrame(cndl_72) # convert to DataFrame
cndl_72_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(cndl_72_df['time'], unit='s') # some time conversion thing from the documentation I don't really get it

while True: # start the stream
    cndl_last = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos("BTCUSD", mt5.TIMEFRAME_M1, 1, 1) # download latest bar
    cndl_last_df = pd.DataFrame(cndl_last) # convert to DataFrame
    cndl_last_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(cndl_last_df['time'], unit='s') # do necessary time conversion

    cndl_72_last_df = cndl_72_df.iloc[[-1]]
    #below line throws an error.
    cndl_72_last_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(cndl_72_last_df['time'], unit='s')

# check if the most recent bar is the same as the most recent entry in bars_frame

    if cndl_last_df.iloc[[-1]].reset_index(drop=True)\
    .equals(cndl_72_last_df):
        print("True", cndl_last_df, cndl_72_last_df)
    else:
        print("False", cndl_last_df, cndl_72_last_df)
        cndl_72_df = pd.concat([cndl_72_df, cndl_last_df])
        print(cndl_72_df)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Errors below:

```
Authorized
C:\Users\hello\Documents\projects\alerter_venv\main_2.py:31: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  cndl_72_last_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(cndl_72_last_df['time'], unit='s')
False                  time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0 2022-02-21 14:36:00  37615.11  37625.11  37581.61  37591.61           65     900            0                   time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
71 2022-02-21 14:36:00  37615.11  37625.11  37581.61  37591.61           65     900            0
                  time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0  2022-02-21 13:25:00  38326.97  38352.76  38295.47  38296.97           60     900            0
1  2022-02-21 13:26:00  38294.47  38312.76  38273.47  38274.97           56     900            0
2  2022-02-21 13:27:00  38274.26  38275.97  38231.97  38266.47           85     900            0
3  2022-02-21 13:28:00  38269.26  38307.47  38231.97  38286.47           81     900            0
4  2022-02-21 13:29:00  38284.51  38295.47  38258.47  38281.51           62     900            0
..                 ...       ...       ...       ...       ...          ...     ...          ...
68 2022-02-21 14:33:00  37648.50  37663.51  37633.00  37642.00           54     900            0
69 2022-02-21 14:34:00  37642.00  37653.26  37611.00  37632.00           54     900            0
70 2022-02-21 14:35:00  37634.50  37636.00  37611.50  37613.11           67     900            0
71 2022-02-21 14:36:00  37615.11  37625.11  37581.61  37591.61           65     900            0
0  2022-02-21 14:36:00  37615.11  37625.11  37581.61  37591.61           65     900            0

[73 rows x 8 columns]
C:\Users\hello\Documents\projects\alerter_venv\main_2.py:31: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  cndl_72_last_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(cndl_72_last_df['time'], unit='s')
True                  time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0 2022-02-21 14:36:00  37615.11  37625.11  37581.61  37591.61           65     900            0                  time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0 2022-02-21 14:36:00  37615.11  37625.11  37581.61  37591.61           65     900            0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hello\Documents\projects\alerter_venv\main_2.py", line 42, in <module>
    time.sleep(10)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Index that is concatenated onto cndl_72_df is not 72 but shows 0 instead, and in the output index 72 and 0 are the same. The newest candle data should become index 72 with index 0 being deleted.

EDIT #3:
code:

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
import pandas as pd
import time

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500) 
pd.set_option('display.width', 1500)      

if not mt5.initialize(): # start mt5
    print("initialize failed")
    mt5.shutdown()

account="FOO" # account info to log into broker
authorized=mt5.login(account, server="FOO")
if authorized:
    print("Authorized")
else:
    print("failed to connect at account #{}, error code: {}".format(account, mt5.last_error()))

# download last 10 bars of EURUSD
cndl_72 = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos("EURUSD", mt5.TIMEFRAME_M1, 1, 72)
cndl_72_df = pd.DataFrame(cndl_72) # convert to DataFrame
cndl_72_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(cndl_72_df['time'], unit='s') # some time conversion thing from the documentation I don't really get it

while True: # start the stream
    cndl_last = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos("EURUSD", mt5.TIMEFRAME_M1, 1, 1) # download latest bar
    cndl_last_df = pd.DataFrame(cndl_last) # convert to DataFrame
    cndl_last_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(cndl_last_df['time'], unit='s') # do necessary time conversion

    cndl_72_last_df = cndl_72_df.iloc[[-1]]

# check if the most recent bar is the same as the most recent entry in bars_frame

    if cndl_72_last_df.equals(cndl_last_df):
        print("True", cndl_last_df, cndl_72_last_df)
    else:
        print("False", cndl_last_df, cndl_72_last_df)
        cndl_72_df = pd.concat([cndl_72_df, cndl_last_df])
        #remove the oldest candle data:
        cndl_72_df.drop(index=cndl_72_df.index[0], axis=0, inplace=True)
        
        """
        Renumber the indexes so that the oldest index (now 1) becomes 
        0 and the rest follow until the last is 71. In the output you can
        see that this expected behavior is not happening:
        """ 
        cndl_72_df.reset_index(drop=True)
        print(cndl_72_df)
    time.sleep(10)
```

output:

```
Authorized
False                  time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0 2022-02-21 17:41:00  38930.11  38970.86  38914.11  38952.79           77     900            0                   time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
71 2022-02-21 17:41:00  38930.11  38970.86  38914.11  38952.79           77     900            0
                  time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
1  2022-02-21 16:31:00  38557.01  38557.01  38462.59  38475.74          100     900            0
2  2022-02-21 16:32:00  38475.80  38590.34  38458.37  38578.34           95    1683            0
3  2022-02-21 16:33:00  38579.34  38615.44  38551.99  38557.46          101     959            0
4  2022-02-21 16:34:00  38562.46  38592.26  38486.15  38513.26           78     900            0
5  2022-02-21 16:35:00  38517.76  38638.82  38513.26  38525.46          100     900            0
..                 ...       ...       ...       ...       ...          ...     ...          ...
67 2022-02-21 17:37:00  38834.26  38852.51  38805.41  38833.76           81     900            0
68 2022-02-21 17:38:00  38836.08  38909.58  38836.08  38909.58           62     900            0
69 2022-02-21 17:39:00  38906.08  39015.11  38903.76  38972.61          104     900            0
70 2022-02-21 17:40:00  38986.11  39001.61  38929.61  38929.61           70     900            0
71 2022-02-21 17:41:00  38930.11  38970.86  38914.11  38952.79           77     900            0

[71 rows x 8 columns]
False                  time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0 2022-02-21 17:41:00  38930.11  38970.86  38914.11  38952.79           77     900            0                   time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
71 2022-02-21 17:41:00  38930.11  38970.86  38914.11  38952.79           77     900            0
                  time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
2  2022-02-21 16:32:00  38475.80  38590.34  38458.37  38578.34           95    1683            0
3  2022-02-21 16:33:00  38579.34  38615.44  38551.99  38557.46          101     959            0
4  2022-02-21 16:34:00  38562.46  38592.26  38486.15  38513.26           78     900            0
5  2022-02-21 16:35:00  38517.76  38638.82  38513.26  38525.46          100     900            0
6  2022-02-21 16:36:00  38527.46  38539.46  38478.96  38511.96           87     900            0
..                 ...       ...       ...       ...       ...          ...     ...          ...
68 2022-02-21 17:38:00  38836.08  38909.58  38836.08  38909.58           62     900            0
69 2022-02-21 17:39:00  38906.08  39015.11  38903.76  38972.61          104     900            0
70 2022-02-21 17:40:00  38986.11  39001.61  38929.61  38929.61           70     900            0
71 2022-02-21 17:41:00  38930.11  38970.86  38914.11  38952.79           77     900            0
0  2022-02-21 17:41:00  38930.11  38970.86  38914.11  38952.79           77     900            0

[71 rows x 8 columns]
True                  time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0 2022-02-21 17:41:00  38930.11  38970.86  38914.11  38952.79           77     900            0                  time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0 2022-02-21 17:41:00  38930.11  38970.86  38914.11  38952.79           77     900            0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hello\Documents\projects\alerter_venv\main_2.py", line 42, in <module>
    time.sleep(10)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

In this third edit I made 2 additional changes under the `else:` statement which should delete the oldest index in the dataframe and renumber all of the indexes.  As you can see the issues in the output are:

1. Indexes aren't being renumbered correctly because you can see index 0 at the end of one of the dataframes, whereas it should always be index 71.
2. I'm guessing the interpreter is evaluating 2 of the same candles with different indexes as being different even though its the same candle, which is why False is testing twice and a duplicate candle gets added.

Answer (score 1):

1. It ***should not pass*** your `assert_frame_equal` test if you are really downloading new data. From the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html), its purpose is to:

> Check that left and right DataFrame are equal.

which means that it will raise an AssertionError if the check fails. If you are downloading new data, you should expect for a different dataframe than before, and then you should expect the dataframe to be not equal, and so you should expect for an AssertionError.

2. `pd.concat([cndl_72_df, cndl_last_df])` ***is not an inplace concat***, meaning you need to assign the outcome of it to a variable in order to store that outcome. You therefore need `cndl_72_df = pd.concat([cndl_72_df, cndl_last_df])`
3. `assert_frame_equal` is more for a test environment, you may instead use [pd.DataFrame.equals](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) to compare two dataframes, it will either give you a True or a False as return. E.g `df1.equals(df2)`
4. I suppose you expect your `cndl_last_df` to grow on new data, therefore there is no point for you to compare if `cndl_last_df` and `cndl_72_last_df` are the same, right? Because they *should* not be the same right? If so, you need to ask yourself what attributes from `cndl_72_last_df` should not repeat in `cndl_last_df`?

**UPDATE**

From your comment

> The objective is to find the latest candlestick in cndl_72_df and see if it is the same as the most recent candlestick from MT5

We can pick the last row by `cndl_72_df.iloc[[-1]]`

```
cndl_72_last_df = cndl_72_df.iloc[[-1]].reset_index(drop=True)
```

and instead do

```
assert_frame_equal([cndl_last_df, cndl_72_last_df])
```

However, as explained, I would prefer

```
cndl_72_last_df.equals(cndl_last_df)
```

but that will require to remove the try-except block and rewrite things in a if-else block. So this is just for your consideration.

Note:

1. the inner bracket in `iloc` lets it return a DataFrame instead of a Series, and we need that because `cndl_last_df` is a DataFrame.
2. `reset_index` makes sure the index of `cndl_72_last_df` starts from zero, which is what `cndl_last_df` is supposed to be.
3. Both dataframe should have the same set of columns and in the same order. I assume they are true as they are retrieved from the same source.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful.  cndl_last_df is the latest candlestick that has formed in MetaTrader5.  cndl_last_df never grows larger as a dataframe, it only has 1 index.  The objective is to find the latest candlestick in cndl_72_df and see if it is the same as the most recent candlestick from MT5.  If it is not the same, the new candlestick (cndl_last_df) gets added to cndl_72_df.  These tests ensure that my 72 candle dataframe always has the latest data. The tests should be mostly "they are the same" and once every minute as a new candle forms the test should show "they are not the same"

Comment: Updated my answer. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks but after making changes I get more errors.

Comment: First I think I have mixed up those variable names: `cndl_72_df`, `cndl_72_last_df` and `cndl_last_df`, now I updated my answer, please synchronize the change.

Comment: Second, please remove `cndl_72_last_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(cndl_72_last_df['time'], unit='s')` as it is redundant. `cndl_72_last_df` is from `cndl_72_df` where the `'time'` column had been converted.

Comment: third revision with changes and more errors added

Comment: mostly pandas method is not *inplace* by default, but if such option is available, you can use it. cndl_72_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

Comment: and you need this instead `cndl_72_last_df = cndl_72_df.iloc[[-1]].reset_index(drop=True)` for the line creating `cndl_72_last_df`

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
import pandas as pd
import time

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500) 
pd.set_option('display.width', 1500)      

if not mt5.initialize():
    print("initialize failed")
    mt5.shutdown()

account="HIDDEN"
authorized=mt5.login(account, server="HIDDEN")
if authorized:
    print("Authorized")
else:
    print("failed to connect at account #{}, error code: {}".format(account, mt5.last_error()))

cndl_72 = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos("BTCUSD", mt5.TIMEFRAME_M1, 1, 5)
cndl_72_df = pd.DataFrame(cndl_72) 
cndl_72_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(cndl_72_df['time'], unit='s') 

while True: # start the stream
    cndl_last = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos("BTCUSD", mt5.TIMEFRAME_M1, 1, 1) # download latest bar
    cndl_last_df = pd.DataFrame(cndl_last) # convert to DataFrame
    cndl_last_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(cndl_last_df['time'], unit='s') # do necessary time conversion

    cndl_72_last_df = cndl_72_df.iloc[[-1]].reset_index(drop=True)

    if cndl_72_last_df.equals(cndl_last_df):
        print("Already on most recent candle.")
    else:
        print("New candle found.\n")
        cndl_72_df = pd.concat([cndl_72_df, cndl_last_df])
        cndl_72_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        cndl_72_df.drop(index=cndl_72_df.index[0], axis=0, inplace=True)
        cndl_72_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        print(cndl_72_df)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Output:

```
Authorized
Already on most recent candle.
Already on most recent candle.
Already on most recent candle.
New candle found.

                 time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0 2022-02-21 21:14:00  37814.26  37825.26  37783.26  37818.76           61     949            0
1 2022-02-21 21:15:00  37818.76  37842.76  37741.10  37765.26           81     900            0
2 2022-02-21 21:16:00  37773.26  37779.26  37662.26  37671.26          125     900            0
3 2022-02-21 21:17:00  37658.26  37769.76  37657.76  37719.12           99     900            0
4 2022-02-21 21:18:00  37721.17  37811.85  37715.22  37775.01          101     900            0
Already on most recent candle.
Already on most recent candle.
Already on most recent candle.
Already on most recent candle.
Already on most recent candle.
New candle found.

                 time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0 2022-02-21 21:15:00  37818.76  37842.76  37741.10  37765.26           81     900            0
1 2022-02-21 21:16:00  37773.26  37779.26  37662.26  37671.26          125     900            0
2 2022-02-21 21:17:00  37658.26  37769.76  37657.76  37719.12           99     900            0
3 2022-02-21 21:18:00  37721.17  37811.85  37715.22  37775.01          101     900            0
4 2022-02-21 21:19:00  37775.85  37778.85  37735.35  37759.51           70     900            0
Already on most recent candle.
Already on most recent candle.
```